# Installing imagick for PHP on OSX El Capitan: issue with included pcre.h file

Tags: php, macos, imagemagick

I am trying to install the imagick wrapper for PHP. I am using OSX, bundled version of PHP and have installed Image Magick using MacPorts. 
When I attempt to install Imagick wrapper I get through the phpize and ./configure steps but the compilation fails.

In the terminal, after I run the 'make' command, everything proceeds happily until I receive this fatal error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/imagick-3.4.1/imagick.c:37:
In file included from /usr/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:27:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:10: fatal error: 'pcre.h' file not found
#include "pcre.h"**
```

I have attempted to create a symlink to the pcre.h file that was installed using MacPorts but El Cap doesn't throws "Operation not permitted" errors when I try and I know that this is related to the new limited super user privs in El Cap.

```
# tried both:
sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/pcre.h /usr/include/php/ext/pcre
sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/pcre.h /usr/include/
```

Can anyone suggest a way that I can get "/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h" to find the file "/opt/local/include/pcre.h"?

I know that I can install PHP via MacPorts and that this might end up being the "simplest" solution but I would prefer to continue using the bundled version of PHP before installing PHP via MacPorts.

Thanks in advance and my apologies since I just found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116844/imagick-extension-install-on-osx-el-capitan/36182604#36182604). I think my question is slightly different and I am too much of a noob on stack exchange to make comments and ask questions (and I certainly am in no position to post an answer :) )

Here by the way is my sequence of shell commands:

```
cd /usr/local/
sudo curl -O https://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.4.1.tgz
sudo tar zxf imagick-3.4.1.tgz
cd imagick-3.4.1
sudo phpize
sudo ./configure --with-imagick=/opt/local
sudo make // fail with include error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your real problem is Mac SIP (System Integrity Protection). When SIP is enabled you can't write anything to /usr (with the exception of /usr/local). Disable it and do the symlink, then try install Imagick wrapper using phpize. Make sure to re enable SIP after installation.

To disable SIP

1)Reboot the Mac and hold down Command + R keys simultaneously after you hear the startup chime, this will boot OS X into Recovery Mode.

2)When the “OS X Utilities” screen appears, pull down the ‘Utilities’ menu at the top of the screen instead, and choose “Terminal”

3)Type the following command into the terminal then hit return:

`csrutil disable; reboot`